Clean gradle build to optimize performance
I want to optimize gradle build performance. But before I can do so, I have to know the old build times, so I can compare it to the new results. However, I have issues to run build without any caches. I have tried to run build from terminal with following command, omitting the cache:
 ./gradlew clean assembleMyflavorDebug --no-build-cache

The build took more than 5 min (OK). However, when I run it again, with no modifications anywhere, it runs for about 30s. It means that there is some additional cache or something that speeds up the build. Can somebody advise, how to run complete gradle builds, without any cache, so I can obtain real values of full build in order to optimize it? Thank you.

Deleting the local Gradle cache and downloading everything again is rather pointless just as precisely measuring the duration. Such one-shot builds only find application, eg. when building inside a container: Dockerfile.
